# Temporary file of AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I want to use AppleScript to create a temporary file and then extract the text from it.
This is the code written by someone else, but I don't understand it at all. Is there a simpler one?

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
set tmpfile to ((path to temporary items folder as string) & "Pashua_" & (characters 3 thru end of ((random number) as string)) as string)
    
set fhandle to open for access tmpfile with write permission
write (config as string) to fhandle as «class utf8»
close access fhandle
    
set posixtmpfile to POSIX path of tmpfile
```

---

**Result**

1. How use the `Applescript` get **Temporary folder?**

   Use Command: `(path to temporary items folder as string)`.
2. You must use the “open for access” command (not open ), otherwise the program will not create a temporary file, and will report an error. This action is like vim: create a new file, if you don’t
3. "open for access" needs to add "with write permission" to support write operations
4. How many times have you performed the "open for access" operation, how many times must you perform the "close access". Just like "open up memory & clean up memory" in other languages
5. The temporary file still needs to be deleted, because even if I execute "close access", the file still exists. So the "temporary file" does not seem to exist

**End**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a simpler one

```
set posixtmpfile to POSIX path of (path to temporary items folder) & "Pashua_" & text 3 thru -1 of ((random number) as string)
set fhandle to open for access posixtmpfile with write permission
write config to fhandle as «class utf8»
close access fhandle
```

but you are **strongly discouraged** from using read/write terminology without error handling. If an error occurs the `fhandle` might be stay open and could cause subsequent errors.

---

This is a less simple but more reliable version. it closes the file (descriptor) in any case.

```
set posixtmpfile to POSIX path of (path to temporary items folder) & "Pashua_" & text 3 thru -1 of ((random number) as string)
try
    set fhandle to open for access posixtmpfile with write permission
    write config to fhandle as «class utf8»
    close access fhandle
on error
    try
        close access posixtmpfile
    end try
end try
```

To get a *real* unique identifier use AppleScriptObjC and the `NSUUID` class of the Foundation framework.
It creates a string with format `01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF`

```
use framework "Foundation"
set uniqueIdentifier to current application's NSUUID's UUID()'s UUIDString as text
```

Comment: For my own learning benefit, is there any reason one couldn't or shouldn't first create an empty file then `write` to it without needing to use `open for access` and `close access` ?

Comment: @CJK No, you could also create an empty file and `write` into that file without open / close. However if you want to append text or replace text partially you have to use open / close. Personally I'm using always open / close

Comment: Thank you, through this, I know which command is used to make the file.